# Memory issues with large amounts of data stored as nested cells in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have large amounts of data stored as nested cells in .mat files. My biggest problem right now is the load times for accessing these files, but I'm wondering if the underlying problem is that I came up with an inefficient way for storing the data and I should restructure it to be smaller.

The full file consists of a cell aray:

`Hemi{1,h}` where there are 52 versions of `h`

`.{n,p}` where there are 85 versions of `n` and up to ~100 versions of `p`

`.Variable` where there are 10 variables, each with ~2500 values

This full file ate up all my memory, so I saved it in parts, aka:

`Hemi1.mat=Hemi{1,1}`
`Hemi2.mat=Hemi{1,2}`

etc.

The next step for this application is to load each file, determine which part of it is an appropriate solution (I need `Hemi{1,h}.{n,p}.Var1`, `Hemi{1,h}.{n,p}.Var2`, and `Hemi{1,h}.{n,p}.Var3` for this, but I still need to keep track of the other Variables), save the solution, then close the file and move to the next one.

1. Is there a faster way to load these files?
2. Is the problem less my dataset and more how I've chosen to store it? Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is quite a lot of data.  I have a few suggestions that you could look into.  The first is to see if you can change the datatypes to something like [Categorical Objects](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/categorical.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com).  They are way more memory efficient.  Also if you are storing strings as your final data this can be quite heavy storage wise.

Second you could look into [HDF5 file storage](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/hdf5-files.html).  I hear it is a nice way to store structured data.

You could finally try to convert your {n,p} arrays into Table structures.  I am not sure if this is better for memory, but tables are nice to work with and it may help you out.  (Depending on your version of Matlab you may not have tables :P).

I hope this helps!

-Kyle

Comment: I have tables, but I'm not sure that they take up any less space. However, the table format would then be more compatible with `datastore', for eaxmple? The data is all floating-point numbers with double precision. I suppose I could make them all single precision?

Comment: Careful 'supposing', only store them to single precision if you know you won't lose precision! Also, you may find saving/loading data quicker without compression, see here https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/mat-file-versions.html#br_4ten 
That is, if you can afford the disk space to be saving huge files without compression!

Comment: From Will's link: "Version 7.3 MAT-files use an HDF5-based format that stores data in compressed chunks. The time required to load part of a variable from a Version 7.3 MAT-file depends on how that data is stored across one or more chunks. Each chunk that contains any portion of the data you want to load must be fully uncompressed to access the data. Rechunking your data can improve the performance of the load operation. To rechunk data, use the HDF5 command-line tools, which are part of the HDF5 distribution."